# The show PySpark function is too long

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I have a parquet (200k, 5) when I read, apply udf function and grouby but show function takes a very long time (~3 hours).

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o142.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 10.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 8) (PC-LAZHAR.home executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
```

I just would like to print my results with df_duration.show() and df_fps.show().

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from ia.utils.aws_module import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import *

conf = SparkConf()
aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key = config()
conf.set('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key', aws_access_key_id)
conf.set('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key', aws_secret_access_key)

spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.parquet(f"s3a://{bucket}/{key}")
df = df.filter(df['key'].contains('.ts'))

# Get the length of the DataFrame using the row counts per rowgroup and file footers
length = "{:,}".format(df.count())

# Print the length of the DataFrame
print(f"The length of the Parquet table is {length}")
> 
metadata_video_udf = udf(metadata_video, StructType([
    StructField("fps", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("duration", FloatType(), True)
]))

df2 = df.withColumn("duration", metadata_video_udf("bucket", "key")["duration"])
df2 = df2.withColumn("fps", metadata_video_udf("bucket", "key")["fps"])

groupby duration and fps and count
df_duration = df2.groupBy("duration").count().orderBy("duration")
df_fps = df2.groupBy("fps").count().orderBy("fps")
```

Comment: Can you try to call show() on intermediate dataframes to determine which operation takes the longest time? What does `metadata_video()` do?

Comment: I call `show()` after `df_fps = df.withColumn("fps", get_fps(df['key']))` and it takes 30s. `metadata_video()` gives me fps and duration of a video